# What does the expression "a shiver of" mean or imply?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does the expression "a shiver of" mean or imply in the following sentence : All of a sudden, electricity flows in an unfamiliar pattern, **a shiver of** current across a circuit board of cells.

I looked it up in a dictionary but I'm still bothered by the curiosity. Can you help me?

Comment: Where did you find this? Was it on am actual physical printed page, or might it simply be an OCR error for *sliver*?

Comment: Without context it’s hard to say. But if it really is talking about current conducting through body cells then it could cause a wave of contraction across the cells- like a *shiver*.

Comment: I don't think *a sliver of current* makes any more sense than *a shiver of current*.

Comment: @Jim The question talks about a 'circuit board' of cells.  Biological cells aren't usually mounted on circuit boards, I assume that the cells are battery cells and that the 'shiver of electricity' is some sort of curreny spontaneously generated by the interaction of the cells, a bit like eddy currents in wound cables.

Comment: @BoldBen - I assumed it was figurative.

Comment: @jim Could be, the language is a bit poetical for describing something physical and technical but I could imagine that cells with approximately the same capacity connected correctly would balance up small differences in potential over a circuit in a way that could be described as 'a shiver' as the electricity flows around them.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the preposition *of* conveys a relationship of agency, means, or cause and effect (see "[of, prep.](https://oed.com/view/Entry/130549)" in the Oxford English Dictionary). For instance, in a phrase like

> a shiver of excitement,

*excitement* may be the cause of the shiver or the occasion for the shiver; *of* helps describe from what state the shiver comes. That usage may be somewhat restrictive; many results for "shiver of" in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) focus on emotional or physical states that would cause someone to shiver, including but not limited to

- shiver of amusement
- shiver of revulsion
- shiver or fear
- shiver of discomfort
- shiver of anticipation
- shiver of chagrin
- shiver of disgust

That said, the usage isn't strictly limited to personal states. I also see the following results:

> a gentle shiver of wind blowing over them

> the hull ripples like a shiver of feathers

> the thrilling shiver of the reaper passing close

> the singing shiver of his whammy bar

> a complex shiver of muscles

So I read **a shiver of current** in the extended sense like *shiver of wind* - the current is the cause of the shiver or helps characterize the shiver. It is a trembling brought about by electric current (if we read it literally) or a trembling analogous to that of electric current (if we read it as part of the metaphor construing cells as circuit boards). That makes sense [in the fuller context of describing neurons firing off](https://magazine.columbia.edu/article/book-review-imagine-how-creativity-works):

> There is a network of neurons in the brain, and the network shifts. All of a sudden, electricity flows in an unfamiliar pattern, a shiver of current across a circuit board of cells.

Comment: From the technical (and more literal) side, we would say that the current is *fluctuating*, perhaps *oscillating*, that it is *transient* or *time-varying* and can ceaselessly vary at high frequencies. All this makes "shiver" a well-suited and satisfying anthropomorphization for current, which is usually considered inanimate but is found here in the context of biological cells.